# Should isolated Majorana fermion be zero energy?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, superconductivity, majorana-fermions

any spinless fermionic operator can be written as summation of two majorana fermionic operators, but these mf operators will be spatially overlap and can't be realised in other words can not be isolated.

but in 1-d atom chain model, the mf operators couple with adjacent sites' operators. thus we have isolated 2 mf ops at the ends of chain each residing at one end.

and these end modes, constitutes a non local fermionic mode with zero energy.

so as a brief summary, isolated mf occurs at the ends, because the mf ops are coupled to mf ops at adjacent site, which leaves 2 ops at the end.
in other words the isolated mf's evident in the non-coupled ops.

now  this is what i understand but here comes the confusing part.
in discrete 1-d case  when we write the Hamiltonian the above picture is very clearly seen whether there is uncoupled mf op or not.

but in the continuous case we are not talking about the sites.
so what is the quantitative parameter that shows whether there is an uncoupled mf op or not?
now i am not at all sure about this remark but ; is it correct to say that;
if there is un coupled mf ops at each end, they must be zero energy?
so the isolated majorana fermions are only exists in the zero energy case?
so if i have majorana modes with non zero energy are they isolated or not?

Comment: What do you call coupled or uncoupled Majorana operators ? For me they corresponds to overlapping wave functions or not in a second quantised description... so there is no formal distinction between lattice sites and continuous space. Comment about your first sentence : *Any complex fermionic operator* (not necessarily spinless) can be decomposed in term of *two real operators*, called Majorana operators. Due to anti-commutation relation of the fermionic creation and destruction operators, Majorana's operators have peculiar properties.

Comment: by couplin i mean paired or not.  it is like the kitaev 1-d chain model.

Comment: The answer to the question was thus : a coupling is a term in the Hamiltonian associating energy to a couple of Majorana modes, like $H=\epsilon_{i,i+1}\gamma_{i}\gamma_{i+1}$, with $\gamma$ a Majorana operator and $i$ a site and $\epsilon_{i,i+1}$ the associated energy. The fact you can not answer this simple question explain why you need to ask indeed. So what you want to know is that in the real space you will have an expression like $H=\epsilon\left(x,y\right)\gamma\left(x\right)\gamma\left(y\right)$. That's it.

Comment: And for the quantitative parameter, check the Kitaev's paper you seem to know already, the answer is there, the topological criterion is the sign of the Pfaffian of the wave-functions associated to the wire.